# What do I replace Vec and HashSet with in a no_std environmement?

Tags: rust, webassembly, rust-no-std

I'm working on a project that's meant to be compiled to webassembly. So I guess I have to mark the library as no_std. But as it currently relies on Vec, String and HashSet quite a lot this seems to be impossible as I get errors for those features.

How can I remove/replace those features without loosing the functionality in a no_std environment like webassembly. I guess I could go for &str instead of String, but what about the others?

If I remove `#![cfg_attr(not(test), no_std)]` and compile the project it seems to work as a webassembly binary. Why is that, if I get errors when adding the line?

Comment: Compiling to webassembly doesn't require `no_std`

Comment: Oh! I thought wasm was a no_std environment. I've seen no_std mentioned in every other post about wasm so that's why I thought so.
https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/book/reference/which-crates-work-with-wasm.html says: `A good rule of thumb is that if a crate supports embedded and #![no_std] usage, it probably also supports WebAssembly.` for example.

Comment: The `wasm32-unknown-unknown` target does have the `std` crate available, but not all parts are implemented. (You can see this [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/76188b6830897a875a1289809c12b5c5d69bb7ef/library/std/src/sys/wasm/mod.rs#L19-L48) in the Rust source code.) So if you try to use `std::fs` or `std::net` in WebAssembly, for example, your code can panic or return an error. But for things like `Vec` and `HashMap` there should be no problems.

Comment: Great! That explains it then! :) Thanks! Are there any reasons to try to keep it no_std in wasm?

Comment: It can help keep binary sizes small.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, you don't need to restrict yourself to `no_std` in WASM, since much of the standard library is available, including both of these collections.

However, if you're building in a real `no_std` environment, you can use `Vec` provided you use the `alloc` crate, which allows you to allocate memory.  `String` is likewise available.  In most situations, you will have some memory allocation available, so `alloc` is an option.

You can't use `HashMap` or `HashSet` in a `no_std` environment because to avoid hash collision attacks, they need to have access to a secure source of random data.  Even `no_std` environments may deal with untrusted data, so preserving this security invariant is important.  There, you can use the `BTreeMap` and `BTreeSet` instead (also from `alloc`), which provide similar functionality with slightly different performance characteristics and slightly different requirements on the data in question.  Because these collections are deterministic, they can be implemented without more than a memory allocator.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [hashbrown](https://crates.io/crates/hashbrown) crate. It’s a standalone export of the Rust standard library’s HashMap, but as mentioned before it does depend on the existence of a global allocator to function.